# finding where index from one dataframe is not in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, one is called now & the other called old. Both have a string index. I am trying to find where a index value is in the **now** dataframe but not in the **old** dataframe.

I write tried the line below & it returns a series of True values

```
new_deals = now.index.isin(old.index)
```

However the **now** dataframe has an index value '4025542MM' which is not in the **old** dataframe & when I test the line below it returns False. So I'm confused why when I use the isin function it is returning True?

```
'4025542MM' in old.index = False
```

**update**

Its hard to copy data examples across. Below is a subset of some of the index values. The **old** dataframe data comes from sql and the index column is nvarchar(20) in sql server. The **now** dataframe data is coming from a text file.

I have tried using strip() but it makes no difference. I don't believe there is any extra white space as far as I can tell. In both dataframes the column is of type object.

```
 3000093MM
 3000161MM
 3000166MM
 3000273MM
 3000285MM
 3000291MM
 3000354MM
 3000458MM
 3000547MM
 3000773MM
 3000938MM
 3001080MM
```

Comment: Is possible add some sample data? `now.index.isin(old.index)` should working well

Comment: probably white space , try adding `strip()` `now.index.strip().isin(old.index.strip())`

Comment: @jezrael please my updated post, hopefully that helps

Comment: @mHelpMe - In my opinion it seems data related problem, very hard to find :(

Comment: @jezrael sadly I agree, thanks anyways

Comment: Are data confidental?

Comment: I think both index values

Comment: yes the data is confidental. Its strange as I have uploaded the now dataframe into sql & can there I can join based on the index values and it shows me which index values are not in one table & vice versa